# Sum variables using R by categories condition

Tags: r

I have a data frame that shows the number of publications by year. But I am interested just in Conference and Journals Publications. I would like to sum all other categories in Others type.

Examples of data frame:

```
year    type                n    
1994    Conference          2    
1994    Journal             3    
1995    Conference         10    
1995    Editorship          3    
1996    Conference         20    
1996    Editorship          2    
1996    Books and Thesis    3
```

And the result would be:

```
year type             n    
1994    Conference    2    
1994    Journal       3    
1995    Conference   10    
1995    Other         3    
1996    Conference   20    
1996    Other         5
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group

Comment: you are not summing the Others- bcause there are two Others. Do you simply want to rename Editorship and Books and Thesis to Others. or Do you want to sum everything post that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `dplyr` we can `replace` anything other than "Journal" or "Conference" to "Other" and then `sum` them by `year` and `type`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(type = sub("^((Journal|Conference))", "Other", type)) %>%
  group_by(year, type) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(n))


#  year       type     n
#  <int>      <chr> <int>
#1  1994 Conference     2
#2  1994    Journal     3
#3  1995 Conference    10
#4  1995      Other     3
#5  1996 Conference    20
#6  1996      Other     5
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
setDT(df1)[, .(n = sum(n)), .(year, type = str_replace(type, 
       '(Journal|Conference)', 'Other'))]
#   year             type  n
#1: 1994            Other  5
#2: 1995            Other 10
#3: 1995       Editorship  3
#4: 1996            Other 20
#5: 1996       Editorship  2
#6: 1996 Books and Thesis  3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
levels(df$type)[levels(df$type) %in% c("Editorship", "Books_and_Thesis")] <- "Other"
aggregate(n ~ type + year, data=df, sum)

#         type year  n
# 1 Conference 1994  2
# 2    Journal 1994  3
# 3      Other 1995  3
# 4 Conference 1995 10
# 5      Other 1996  5
# 6 Conference 1996 20
```

Input data:

```
df <- structure(list(year = c(1994L, 1994L, 1995L, 1995L, 1996L, 1996L, 
  1996L), type = structure(c(2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Other", 
  "Conference", "Journal"), class = "factor"), n = c(2L, 3L, 10L, 
  3L, 20L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("year", "type", "n"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```